# Windows forms: PropertyGrid

Tags: winforms, propertygrid

Does setting PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = null; effects the actual object?
eg:

```
Button b = new Button();
System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid pg = new System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid();
pg.SelectedObject = b;

pg.SelectedObject = null;
```

What will happen to Button b? will it be null?

Thanks & regards,
Vishal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting PropertyGrid.SelectedObject only affects the PropertyGrid. If you set SelectedObject to null, it means that there is simply no object displayed in the property grid. In your example, button b will not be affected.